# How to correct my code. To simplify my answer in a single array result

Tags: c#, linq

Here's my code. I was wondering if how can I store the value in a single variable array format. I don't know the next step. I am newly in LINQ and C#.

```
var result = (from x in _context.DwPropertyMasters
   where
     x.ShowMapPoint == "Y"
   select new
     {
       x.LandId,
       a = x.Development == null || x.Development == "" ? x.Location : x.Development,
       x.MapPointX,
       x.MapPointY,
       AreaSize = x.AreaSize ?? 0,
       Premium = x.Premium ?? 0,
       b = (x.Premium == 0 ? null : x.Premium) * 100000000 / (x.AreaSize == 0 ? null : x.AreaSize),

       c = (from z in _context.DwPropertyDetails
           where (z.TransactionPrice > 0 || z.TransactionPrice != null) && z.LandId == x.LandId
           group z by z.LandId into g
           select (g.Sum(p => p.TransactionPrice) == 0 ? null : g.Sum(p => p.TransactionPrice)) / (g.Sum(p => p.ActualSize) == 0 ? null : g.Sum(p => p.ActualSize))).FirstOrDefault(),

           d = (x.AreaSize2 == 0 ? null : x.AreaSize2) == 0 ? 0 : (x.Premium == 0 ? null : x.Premium) * 100000000 / (x.AreaSize2 == 0 ? null : x.AreaSize2),
           x.LandType,
           e = (from y in _context.DwPropertyDetails
           where (y.TransactionPrice > 0 || y.TransactionPrice != null) && y.LandId == x.LandId
           select new
           {
             a = 1
           }).Count()
        }).ToArray();

        return View(result);
```

The result I get is like this:

```
[
  {
    "LandId":1,
    "a":"2GETHER",
    "MapPointX":"22.37607871816074",
    "MapPointY":"113.96758139133453",
    "AreaSize":118046,
    "Premium":5.51,
    "b":4667.671924,
    "c":13198,
    "d":4148.815215,
    "LandType":"PROPERTY",
    "e":169
  }
]
```

All I want is like this:

```
[1,'2GETHER',22.37607871816074,113.96758139133453,118046,5.51,4668.00000000000000000000,13198,4149.00000000000000000000,'PROPERTY',169]
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

```
return View(new object[] { 
    result.LandId,
    result.a,
    result.MapPointX,
    result.MapPointY,
    result.AreaSize,
    result.Premium,
    result.b,
    result.c,
    result.d,
    result.LandType,
    result.e
});
```

Comment: Thank You, for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Just to expand a bit on the previous answer from devio, when you do:

```
.Select( new { ... } ).ToArray()
```

You're actually telling it to give you an array of new dynamically created objects.  When the dynamic object is created, it derives property names automatically for you. It ends up looking like a dictionary of key value pairs. You could try to force it to give you an object array instead of a dynamic type.  Something like:

```
var result = _context.DwPropertyMasters
   .Where( x => x.ShowMapPoint == "Y")
   .Select( x => new object[] { x.LandId, x.MapPointX, ... })
   .ToArray();
```

The difference is that instead of asking it for an array of dynamic objects, you're asking it for an array of object arrays.